# LoggerFields para Syslog (escrever prioridade e stack trace)

Tags: java, log4j2, syslog

Log4j pode enviar logs para o Papertrail usando um syslog appender ([documentação](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/java-log4j-logging/)):

```
log4j.appender.syslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.syslog.Facility=LOCAL7 
log4j.appender.syslog.FacilityPrinting=false 
log4j.appender.syslog.Header=true 
log4j.appender.syslog.SyslogHost=<host>.papertrailapp.com:XXXXX
log4j.appender.syslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=%p: (%F:%L) %x %m %n
```

Note a conveniente propriedade `ConversionPattern`.

---

Eu consegui colocar algo semelhante para funcionar no log4j2:

```
Syslog:
  name: Syslog
  id: [my-id]
  appName: [my-app]
  protocol: UDP
  format: RFC5424
  facility: local7
  host: <host>.papertrailapp.com
  port: XXXXX
  includeMDC: true
  mdcId: mdc
```

Isso funciona e e escreve mensagens no formato RFC5424 padrão:

```
May 14 14:31:36 [server] [app]: Minha mensagem de log
```

---

O que eu realmente quero é uma mensagem com informação de prioridade, bem como stack traces inteiros:

```
May 14 14:31:36 [server] [app]: ERROR Minha mensagem de log MyException
        at package1.MyClass.method1(MyClass.java:20)
        at ...
```

Parece que [LoggerFields](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) devem fazer isso, mas eu não consigo fazer funcionar:

```
 loggerFields:
   LoggerFields:
     KeyValuePair:
       key: priority
       value: "%p"
     KeyValuePair:
       key: exception
       value: "%ex"
```

Como eu posso fazer o log4j2 escrever em syslog utilizando o formato desejado?

---

#### Cross-post: [SOEn - LoggerFields for Syslog (output log priority and stack trace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244901)